# Access elements of individual tuple from a list of tuples

Tags: c++, list, stl, tuples

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <list>
#include <tuple>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    list<tuple<char,double,double>> XYZ_Widget_Store;

    ifstream infile;
    infile.open("data.text");

    char x; // S, P, R
    double a,b; 

    for(;infile >> x >> a >> b;){
        XYZ_Widget_Store.push_back(make_tuple(x,a,b));
    }

    infile.close();

    for(list<int>::iterator it = XYZ_Widget_Store.begin(); it !=
      XYZ_Widget_Store.end(); ++it){
        cout << *it.get<0> << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Let's say that the first item on my `list` contains a `tuple ('a',1,1)` how do I get the first element 'a' from that tuple? usually it is just `get<0>(mytuple)` but being in a list makes it difficult to understand. I want to iterate through the list and get every first element from every element in the list. The element of the `list` is itself a `tuple`.

Comment: Any reason why your first `for` loop is not written as a `while`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're going to use C++11, you might as well use other nice features like `auto` and the for-each loop. Here is how you might re-write that last `for` loop:

```
for (auto& tup : XYZ_Widget_Store) {
    cout << get<0>(tup) << endl;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I actually was not familiar with that feature

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `get<0>(*it)` to get the first element because `it` is the pointer to tuple.  So, your statement in the `for` loop should be:

```
cout << get<0>(*it) << endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

If `it` is an `list<T>::iterator`, then `*it` will give you the corresponding object of type `T`. So, you need to use `get<0>(*it)` to access the appropriate tuple element. You have another error in your `for` loop : Instead of

```
list<int>::iterator it = XYZ_Widget_Store.begin()
```

you need

```
list<tuple<char,double,double>>::iterator it = XYZ_Widget_Store.begin().
```

If you are using C++11, you can also do

```
auto it = XYZ_Widget_Store.begin()
```